# Shared instance of a custom NSObject is lost for some reason

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsobject

I've run into an issue which is confusing me a lot to tell you the truth.

I have a shared instance of MAOrders which I grab when I first initWithNibName in a specific view controller.

The shared instance is saved to the device using NSFileManager and that all works correctly. I can grab the saved data and all of that, that isn't an issue, but it could be effecting what the real problem is so keep that in mind...

Now this is all well and good, the variable ordersController gets this object and the object is allocated to that variable.

However, when I finally present that view controller, the ordersController variable points to nothing and it causes a major crash.

What could be doing this?

**EDIT**
This is what is happening. In `initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil` I allocate `ordersController` with a shared instance of `MAOrders` which is a custom NSObject.
If I NSLog this object, I receive the following: `<MAOrders: 0x6b3e080>`

Now, in `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` the application crashes. I then check what ordersController is equal to and get the following: `0x6b3e080 does not appear to point to a valid object.`

Where am I going wrong?

**ANOTHER EDIT**
Here is the MAOrders singleton code.

```
//
//  Created by Sebastien Peek on 3/11/11.
//  Copyright (c) 2011 NetStart. All rights reserved.
//

#import "MAOrders.h"
#import "MAOrder.h"

@implementation MAOrders
@synthesize pastOrders, currentOrders;

static MAOrders *ordersState;

+ (id)sharedMAOrdersInstance {

@synchronized(self) {

    if (!ordersState) {

        NSLog(@"Order State");

        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
        NSString *dataPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Data"];

        NSString *dataFileString = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Orders.archive"];

        NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:dataFileString];
        NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
        [data release];

        ordersState = [[unarchiver decodeObjectForKey:@"MAOrders"] retain];
        [unarchiver finishDecoding];
        [unarchiver release];

    }

    if (!ordersState) {
        ordersState = [[MAOrders alloc] init];

    }
}

return ordersState;
} 


- (id)init {

if ([pastOrders count] == 0) {

    pastOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

}

if ([currentOrders count] == 0) {

    currentOrders = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: nil];

}

return self;

}

- (void)addOrderToPastOrders:(MAOrder *)pastOrder {

[pastOrders addObject:pastOrder];
[self performSelector:@selector(postSaveNotification)];

}

- (void)removeOrderFromPast:(MAOrder *)removeOrder {

[pastOrders removeObject:removeOrder];
[self performSelector:@selector(postSaveNotification)];
// [removeOrder clearAllItems];

}

- (void)addOrderToCurrentOrders:(MAOrder *)currentOrder {

NSLog(@"Current Orders: %@", currentOrders);

[currentOrders addObject:currentOrder];
[self performSelector:@selector(postSaveNotification)];

}

- (void)removeOrderFromCurrent:(MAOrder *)removeOrder {

[currentOrders removeObject:removeOrder];
[self performSelector:@selector(postSaveNotification)];
// [removeOrder clearAllItems];

}

- (void)addOrderFromCurrentToPast:(MAOrder *)currentToPast {

[currentOrders removeObject:currentToPast];
[pastOrders addObject:currentToPast];

[self performSelector:@selector(postSaveNotification)];

}

- (void)postSaveNotification {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"ordersNeedToSave" object:nil];

}

- (void)dealloc {



}

#pragma mark NSCoding

#define kPastOrders         @"pastOrders"
#define kCurrentOrders      @"currentOrders"

- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {

NSLog(@"Orders Encoding");

[encoder encodeObject:pastOrders forKey:kPastOrders];
[encoder encodeObject:currentOrders forKey:kCurrentOrders];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {

NSLog(@"Orders Decoding");

if ((self = [super init])) {

    pastOrders = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kPastOrders];
    currentOrders = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:kCurrentOrders];

    NSLog(@"CURRENT ORDERS: %@", currentOrders);
    NSLog(@"ORDER MENU NAME: %@", [[[currentOrders objectAtIndex:0] menu] name]);
    NSLog(@"PAST ORDERS: %@", pastOrders);

}

return self;

}


@end
```

That's the complete .m file.

Comment: yes that is NECESSARY :)

Comment: Provided what I do and what I get returned. What code do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason that may cause this problem is unbalanced number of retains and releases. Maybe when you're creating the shared instance of MAObjects it is autoreleased and gets released after the initWithNib... is called or you could assign shared instance of MAObject without retaining it and then released that.

It's impossible to say without the real code. Just find all places where the shared MAObject is called and check the retain/release calls. You can also put the breakpoint inside the dealloc of MAObject and see where it is actually destroyed.

Comment: You're right, I hit the `dealloc` method as soon as I had the instance. The issue is, I never send ordersController the release method which is weird as to why it is being deallocated...

Comment: Have dived a little deeper. In my .h file where I declare ordersController, how should I be propertising it so it doesn't dealloc? It is currently propertised like this: `@property (nonatomic, retain) MAOrders *ordersController;`

Comment: if you told that MAOrder is the shared object then there are only two possibilities: MAObjects is a singleton and should be returned via the class method of MAObjects like [MAObject sharedInstance]; or it is an attribute of another singleton and should be returned via the property of that singleton: [MYSingleton shared].ordersConntroller

Comment: Have added in the code for the MAOrders.m file. Please check out the question.

Comment: Figured out the issue, your answer aided me in determining the issue, therefore, accepted! :D